# Magento Server is at 100% CPU after installing Extension

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I just installed a new Extension via Composer:

```
$ composer require mageworx/module-advancedproductoptions
```

This is the output:

```
Using version ^2.16 for mageworx/module-advancedproductoptions
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         Package operations: 11 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionbase (2.8.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionvisibility (2.0.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optiontemplates (2.5.7): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionswatches (2.2.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionfeatures (2.9.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionskupolicy (2.1.5): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionlink (2.0.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optioninventory (2.6.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optiondependency (2.3.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing mageworx/module-optionadvancedpricing (2.0.3): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Then I did a

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Which was already executed very slowly but didn't show any errors.
Now when I open the homepage I get a timeout and I can see that the server is on 100% CPU constantly.

I can see with top that this is caused by about 15 different php7.2 processes

How can I find out what is causing this?
Which logs files can I check?
Did I miss some step in the installation process?

Comment: If you use php-fpm, increase the max_children settings.

Comment: Make sure your caches enabled after running `composer update` or `setup:upgrade`. It was disabled for me after update via composer.